# Sorting list of by their X and Y property

Tags: vb.net, sorting, listof

I have a list of "clsLabel":

```
Private _ListOfAllLabels As New List(Of clsLabel)

Public Class clsLabel
    Public Name As String
    Public X As Double
    Public Y As Double
End Class
```

X and Y define the location of the Label.

How could I sort my List(of clsLabel) in such a way that it's sorted by Y and then by X ascendingly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `List(Of T)` class has its own `Sort` method that will sort in-place. It allows you to use an `IComparer(Of T)`, which you should if you want to do lots of sorting and especially if you want it to be configurable. For a one-off sort though, just use the overload that accepts a `Comparison(Of T)` delegate:

```vb
_ListOfAllLabels.Sort(Function(l1, l2)
                          Dim result = l1.Y.CompareTo(l2.Y)

                          If result = 0 Then
                              result = l1.X.CompareTo(l2.X)
                          End If

                          Return result
                      End Function)
```

In .NET, sorting is done by defining a comparison between two objects of a type and then performing that comparison repeatedly on pairs of list items based on an algorithm. The comparison should return an `Integer` value less than 1 if the first item should precede the second, a value greater than 1 if the second item should precede the first and zero if they are equivalent. Types that implement the `IComparable`/`IComparable(Of T)` inreface(s), which includes all the VB fundamental types, have such a comparison built in, which is what the `CompareTo` method used above is.

If you would like to learn more about .NET sorting, I've created a multi-part blog post on the subject [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/06/sorting-arrays-and-collections-part-1.html).

Comment: @tmighty, you might check out the link in my edit.